# Trouble finding the successor of a key in a balanced binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

As the question states, I'm trying to find an algorithm to find the successor of a key 'k' in balanced binary search tree. I think a balanced BST is the same as an AVL tree (correct me if I'm wrong). I was hoping I could do this in one pass in O(log n) time, but everything I've found says I need to go down the right side of the tree, then the left. I'm new at the whole trees thing and still find it a little confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Given an element _k_ stored in your tree, you want to find the element _j_ of your tree such that there is no element _i_ verifying _k_ < _i_ < _j_ ? Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

In a binary search tree, you have two path option to go down : *left* or *right*.
Now suppose we have an element *k* in a node *N*. We want to find *k*'s successor, which is the smallest element of the tree which is greater than *k*.

There are 3 use cases here :

- *N* has a non-NULL *right* child : the leftmost element of the *right* subtree is *k*'s successor.
- *N* has not such *right* child and is the ***left*** child of its parent *P*. In this case, *P* holds the successor of *k*.
- Finally, *N* is the ***right*** child of its parent *P*. Then, to find its successor you must follow a more elaborate procedure shown below ...

Starting from *S* = *Parent(P)* : while *S* ≠ Root *AND* *P ≠ Left(S)*

1. *P ← S*
2. *S ← Parent(S)*

If *S* = Root and *P* = *Right(S)*, then *k* was the maximum element of the tree ... Otherwise, just perform the following loop after setting *S ← Right(S)*:

While *S* ≠ NULL :

1. *P ← S*
2. *S ← Left(S)*

When this loop ends, *P* holds *k*'s successor.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So, I have to go down both sides either way?

Comment: @pfinferno You have to figure out in which of the 3 cases you are and act appropriately.

Comment: Oh I see now! That makes sense. Thank you very much (you too Henry).

Comment: I'm sorry, I may just be new to this. But, what is Left()?

Answer (score 0):

If the node with key k has a right subtree, it is the leftmost node in that subtree.
Otherwise, if the node with key k is a left child it is the parent of this node.
Otherwise, find the closest ancestor of the node other than its immediate parent that has a right subtree it is the leftmost node in that subtree. If no such ancestor exists, the node was the maximum and does not have a successor.

Since the tree is balanced, you can always find it in O(log n).